# Vertical line on the right of the image while using filter: blur()

Tags: css, web, sass, web-deployment

I am building a story section for the site. Following is the scss code for a story:

```
    .story{
    width: 75%;
    background-color: $color-white;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: .1rem;
    padding: 4rem;
    padding-left: 5.5rem;
    transform: skewX(-12deg);

    &__shape{
        height: 15rem;
        width: 15rem;
        float: left;
        shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
        clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
        transform: translateX(-1.5rem) skewX(12deg);
        position: relative;
    }

    &__img{
        height: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1.4);
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    &__text{
        transform: skewX(12deg);
    }

    &__caption{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,20%);
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: $color-white;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .5s;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    &:hover &__caption{
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &:hover &__img{
        transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1);
        filter: blur(3px) brightness(80%);
    }
}
```

When I hover a vertical line appears on the right of image and goes away when unhovered. Following are the images of problem.

Without hover:
[image: Without Hover]

With hover:
[image]

This problem only appears on chrome and not on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common `filter: blur();` and `clip-path` problem. You shape is a circle, so there is a `border-radius` solution.

Try to add to the image parent element:

```
&__shape{
  /* add */      
  border-radius: 100%; /* will do the same circle form = your clip-path */
  overflow: hidden; /* will hide everything outside the form, including your line */
}
```

`overflow: hidden;` + `border-radius: 100%;` on the parent element will hide that bug.